# Get difference with previous value and with next value

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe like this. A small sample actually the df is bigger:

```
LOW   1  4  NA 
MID   3  4  4
HIG   2  5  4
```

And would like to get the difference for LOW and HIG with MID so the ending df would be like this:

```
LOW   2  0  NA 
MID   3  4  4
HIG   1  1  0
```

So you're getting: LOW = 3 - 1 = 2 and HIG = 3 - 2 = 1. I cand do it via VBA macros but want to scale with R.

Comment: The maths isn't clear to me. If you want both LOW and HIG to be subtracted from MID, shouldn't your final row for HIG read 1, -1, 0 rather than 1, 1, 0?

Comment: Column names are id v1 v2 v3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with `mutate_if/mutate_at`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ case_when(grp != 'MID' ~ 
         abs(. - .[grp == 'MID']), TRUE ~ .))
#   grp v1 v2 v3
#1 LOW  2  0 NA
#2 MID  3  4  4
#3 HIG  1  1  0
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
i1 <- df1$grp == 'MID'
df1[!i1, -1] <- abs(df1[!i1, -1] - rep(unlist(df1[i1, -1]), each = sum(!i1)))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(grp = c("LOW", "MID", "HIG"), v1 = c(1L, 3L, 2L
), v2 = c(4L, 4L, 5L), v3 = c(NA, 4L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: It works... no idea why! but it works cannot believe R can be so cryptic.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `'LOW'`, `'HIG'` rows after subtracting by `'MID'` :

```
df1[df1$grp == 'LOW', -1] <- abs(df1[df1$grp == 'MID',-1]- df1[df1$grp == 'LOW',-1])
df1[df1$grp == 'HIG', -1] <- abs(df1[df1$grp == 'MID',-1]- df1[df1$grp == 'HIG',-1])

df1
#  grp v1 v2 v3
#1 LOW  2  0 NA
#2 MID  3  4  4
#3 HIG  1  1  0
```